# override base class methods in resharper c++

Tags: resharper-c++

I'm using VS 2012 with Resharper C++.

Is there a way to look at member functions of the base class that can be overridden, and then generate appropriate code in the header/source files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is - you can either use the "Generate overriding members" context action on the name of a derived class, or invoke the "Overriding members" generate code action from inside it. Once you have the declarations of overriding functions inserted, you can invoke the "Generate definitions by declarations" context action to also add the definitions.